# trapping drag-and-drop at design time in Delphi for a TCustomGroupBox descendant

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'm developing a tCustomGroupBox in Delphi 2010 and I want to trap drag-and-drop operations at design time.

I've tried to trap StartDrag and DragDrop, but it seems that those methods does not respond at design time.

How can I implement that capability?

Comment: What are you trying to trap exactly? Please provide more details.

Comment: I'll try to be more explicit:

Comment: I'll try to be more explicit:
I implemented a component descendant from TCustomGroupBox. In design time, I drop it on a form or any other container, and I want that the component be notified when user drag it along that form or container.
As I said before, neither StartDrag nor DragDrop events are triggered in design time.

Comment: No, because the component is not actually being dragged, as far as the VCL is concerned. I don't think you can detect design-time dragging without hooking into the IDE designer itself. But you should be able to override `SetBounds()`, at least, which gets called whenever the component's `Left/Top/Width/Height` properties change.